# Java file delete error

Tags: java

I want to delete a file in java.It generate this result. How may I delete the file. And what is the reason for this.

```
File l_file = new File(path);
System.out.println(l_file.exists()); //returns true
System.out.println(l_file.delete()); //returns false
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this issue reproducible with this code? Please check if you have locks on the object.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you have permissions to delete the file?

Comment: what does path represent ?? file name or directory ??

Comment: @Thushara : look for file permissions

Comment: This is a normal file I created to store object. path is correct. No errors with this code. Is there any other way to delete this file.

Comment: Can you delete it manually?

Comment: yes can delete manually.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why a file deletion would fail. For instance if another process is holding a handle to it, or if you don't have permissions to delete this file. In both scenarios you will be able to check the file for existence, but not to delete it.

Comment: If it holding another process how may I released from it. Some time file delete successfully. But some time it fails. Cant figure out the reason.

Comment: You should figure out **which** process is holding a handle to the file and make sure the process releases the handle before you attempt to delete it.

Comment: Is there a way to release file from the all processes manually.

Comment: On windows I use [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to find the process holding a handle and then if needed terminate it.

Comment: Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: @Thushara I am sorry but I am not aware of a way to do that in java, though I am sure it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why a file can't be deleted. The most likely ones are that the file is open in another process or that your process has launched with less privileges than those required to delete that file.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason is that the `path` can be a directory

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) `File#delete()`:

`If this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in order to be deleted.`

Check if the path is not empty directory:

```
if (l_file.isDirectory()) {
   String[] files = l_file.list();
      if (files.length > 0) {
         System.out.println("The " + l_file.getPath() + " is not empty!");
      }
}
```

---

Another reason why you couldn't remove a `path` is that you have not permitions

Check your permitions:

```
if (l_file.canWrite())
   l_file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to check if it is a file (not a directory) its permissions using `File` methods:

```
boolean isFile() // if it is a directory it must be empty
boolean canWrite()
boolean canRead()
boolean canExecute()
```

Besides, as you can read in Java API: "On some operating systems it may not be possible to remove a file when it is open and in use by this Java virtual machine or other programs."

If you are in Linux, you can try `lsof <file_name>` in order to know which process has opened this file.

Comment: It is happen not because of permission. I checked it.

Comment: Maybe it is the second part, if you are in Linux, you can try `lsof <file_name>` in order to know which process has opened this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `FileChannel.lock()` or `FileChannel.tryLock()` to see if you can acquire the lock before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it.

1. Go to the File and change its properties to full control
2. If you opened an classes PrintWriter or Scanner you should you should close the class especially Scanner object with `.Close`
   [image]